# How to Type word by word or line by line in Phaser Js?

Tags: javascript, animation, phaser-framework

I need an animation in which a sentanace needs to be shown word by word. I was thinking of splitting the sentanace by space or dot, and then a timer or loop to display them. I am confused where to use this, in `create` or `update` function? 
I also dont need the `bitmapText` option.

I have seen examples like, but I dont know how to use this in update function:

```
animateTextShow: function(textObject,message,fps){
    if(!fps || fps == 0){
      textObject.setText(message);
    }else{
      var nextWordIndex = 1;
      var id;
      var words = message.split(' ');
      id = setInterval(function(){
        textObject.setText(words.slice(0,nextWordIndex).join(' '));
        ++nextWordIndex;
        if(nextWordIndex >= words.length){
          clearInterval(id);
        }
      },1000/fps);
    }
  }
```

Can anyone give any ideas with some example code?

Comment: I don't have real experience with phaser, but my guess would be to split the words in the create function as well as an index of the last displayed word. And then use the setInterval function in the update function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually need an update loop for this at all. The way I would do it is to split the content up into lines, and then split each line up into an array - one word per element. Then using a Phaser Timer I'd loop through the line, adding one word at a time to the Text string. When it gets to the end of the line add a carriage return and advanced to the next line of the content.

Here is a complete example - this was written under Phaser 2.4.2 but should work on earlier versions without issue. Sorry it's quite long but I included lots of text so you can see it working properly.

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { create: create });

var content = [
    "The sky above the port was the color of television, tuned to a dead channel.",
    "`It's not like I'm using,' Case heard someone say, as he shouldered his way ",
    "through the crowd around the door of the Chat. `It's like my body's developed",
    "this massive drug deficiency.' It was a Sprawl voice and a Sprawl joke.",
    "The Chatsubo was a bar for professional expatriates; you could drink there for",
    "a week and never hear two words in Japanese.",
    "",
    "Ratz was tending bar, his prosthetic arm jerking monotonously as he filled a tray",
    "of glasses with draft Kirin. He saw Case and smiled, his teeth a webwork of",
    "East European steel and brown decay. Case found a place at the bar, between the",
    "unlikely tan on one of Lonny Zone's whores and the crisp naval uniform of a tall",
    "African whose cheekbones were ridged with precise rows of tribal scars. `Wage was",
    "in here early, with two joeboys,' Ratz said, shoving a draft across the bar with",
    "his good hand. `Maybe some business with you, Case?'",
    "",
    "Case shrugged. The girl to his right giggled and nudged him.",
    "The bartender's smile widened. His ugliness was the stuff of legend. In an age of",
    "affordable beauty, there was something heraldic about his lack of it. The antique",
    "arm whined as he reached for another mug.",
    "",
    "",
    "From Neuromancer by William Gibson"
];

var line = [];

var wordIndex = 0;
var lineIndex = 0;

var wordDelay = 120;
var lineDelay = 400;

function create() {

    text = game.add.text(32, 32, '', { font: "15px Arial", fill: "#19de65" });

    nextLine();

}

function nextLine() {

    if (lineIndex === content.length)
    {
        //  We're finished
        return;
    }

    //  Split the current line on spaces, so one word per array element
    line = content[lineIndex].split(' ');

    //  Reset the word index to zero (the first word in the line)
    wordIndex = 0;

    //  Call the 'nextWord' function once for each word in the line (line.length)
    game.time.events.repeat(wordDelay, line.length, nextWord, this);

    //  Advance to the next line
    lineIndex++;

}

function nextWord() {

    //  Add the next word onto the text string, followed by a space
    text.text = text.text.concat(line[wordIndex] + " ");

    //  Advance the word index to the next word in the line
    wordIndex++;

    //  Last word?
    if (wordIndex === line.length)
    {
        //  Add a carriage return
        text.text = text.text.concat("\n");

        //  Get the next line after the lineDelay amount of ms has elapsed
        game.time.events.add(lineDelay, nextLine, this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update runs around 60 times per second.

So if you want to use loop dont use it in update().

My suggestion is adding your sentence to an array character by character and then add characters one by one Like this :

```
create:function(){

    var  sentencearr="your sentence".split('');
        var i =-1;
              game.time.events.loop(Phaser.Timer.SECOND*2, function() {

                  i++;
                  game.add.text(i*5,0,sentencearr[i]);

        }, this);  }
```